Extendability of a measure on a filtration in terms of positive martingale
Let $\mathcal F = (\mathcal F_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a filtration and $M_t$ is a continuous positive $(\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$-martingale with mean $1$. Consider
$$ \mathcal F_\infty = \sigma \left(_{t\geq 0} \mathcal F_t \right)$$
Define the measures
$$ \forall t \geq 0, \forall A \in \mathcal F_t, \qquad \mathbb Q_t(A) := E_{\mathbb P}[1_AM_t]. $$
Can we extend $ (\mathbb Q_t)_{t\geq 0}$ to a $\sigma$-additive measure $\mathbb Q$ on $\mathcal F_\infty$?
Clearly, if the martingale $M$ is uniformly integrable, this is immediate. What about the non-uniformly integrable case?
I have consulted several threads on this site but nothing really useful. For example, this answer is not particularly useful.
Context: The problem arises from an exam my brother just took, where his teacher said: pretend that there exists a measure $\mathbb Q$ such that
$$ \forall t\geq0, A \in \mathcal F_t, \qquad \mathbb Q(A) = E_{\mathbb P}[1_AB_{T\wedge t}], $$
where $B$ is a $(\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$-Brownian motion starting at 1 and $T$ is the first time it hits $0$ and then blah blah. Note that $(B_{T\wedge t})_{t\geq 0}$ is a positive martingale, but not uniformly integrable.
I could do all the questions in this exam except the statement: $X_t = \frac{1}{B_t}$ is a uniformly integrable, continuous local martingale under $\mathbb Q$ (if possible, can you give me some hints?). I could only prove that $X$ is positive super-martingale and converge a.s. to $0$ under $\mathbb Q$ using $\mathbb Q[T =+\infty] = 1$.
It bugs me so much without knowing if there is such an extension or not. If this is true, it provides an example of a uniformly integrable, continuous local martingale which is not a martingale.
Thank you!

Similar to the linked answer you do not find particularly useful, the authors Karatzas & Shreve of Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus refer to that book Probability Measures on Metric Spaces by Parthasarathy. Therein is a very technical theorem that allows to extend the measures $\mathbb Q_t$ to $\mathbb Q$ under some conditions on the filtration. Nothing comes for free.
